# jupyter lab script to set up view layout

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have some python functions to create graphical interface components in jupyter (lab) using ipywidgets. For my specific application, it's very useful to create different views for different cell outputs containing different widgets. I do this manually with "right click / create new view for output". However, sometimes this process gets annoying when I close everything and come back to work on it later, because I have to redo this layout manually every time and I was wondering if there's a way to write a single script (that I can run from some command line interface) that basically sets this up automatically, i.e. run commands in a jupyter lab session, get specific output cells and send them to different views, etc. Is there a way to do this?